# Limiting processes on multtiprocess

Tags: python

Using this very simple example how i can limit the process to 5 each time, instead processing all the 90 at same time?

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(90):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

The  solution is creating a Pool of 5 workers (in your case), and use that pool to handle each of your requests.

If you're reasonably new to Python and need an introduction on threads and processes, I think this presentation is fairly good:
http://www.slideshare.net/pvergain/multiprocessing-with-python-presentation

Go through it, you'll learn some things, and near the end you'll get an example on the usage of Pools.

Comment: Hi,

I'm new to python, could you please give an example of how could i apply your advice on my question?

Comment: Thank you for giving the link with the info instead  replying with a full solution =)

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing.Pool`  is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for your Task with threading and a Queue that is 5 threads long:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading, Queue

class ThreadedWorker(threading.Thread):
        jobQueue = Queue.Queue()

        def run( self ):
                while True:
                        num = ThreadedWorker.jobQueue.get()

                        """thread worker function"""
                        print 'Worker:', num

                        ThreadedWorker.jobQueue.task_done()

class MainClass(ThreadedWorker):
        def __init__( self ):
                self.maxThreads = 5
                self.startTest()

        def startTest( self ):
                meine_threads = [ThreadedWorker() for i in range( self.maxThreads )]

                for thread in meine_threads:
                        thread.setDaemon(True)
                        thread.start()

                for i in range(90):
                        ThreadedWorker.jobQueue.put( i )

                ThreadedWorker.jobQueue.join()

mc = MainClass()
```